# Session is not storing variables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm facing dilemma that the session I created to store the varibale(the user name) is not showing. I want to show the user name in the `maindash.html` after when the user sign up in `index.php`.

**maindash.html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>
        MY SITE PLANNER | DASHBOARD
      </title>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"\>
      <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    </head>
    <body class="formbg">
      <div class="container-fluid pi">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <p class="ppp">
                    <img src="image/my-site-planner-logo.png" class="ppp" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <p class="up">
            <!--        Hi, <a href="#">user</a> -->
              <a href="#">Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION["name"]; ?></a>
                        <a href="#">settings</a>
                        <a href="#">logout</a>
                </p>
                <p id="dt">
                    System:
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-fluid fill">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="navbar">
              <ul class="nalink">
                <li>
                  <a href="trans.html">ViewIncomeStatement</a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="siteform.html">View/AddSite</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="vendor.html">View/AddVendor</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="item.html">View/AddItem</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3 class="side">
              Summary of your site 
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-success view" name="submit" type="submit" >
              View Income Statement
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="table-responsive line">
              <table class="table table-bordered dem">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="hd">
                    <th width="3">Sr.</th>
                    <th width="6">Site Name</th>
                    <th width="6">Incomes</th>
                    <th width="6">Expenses</th>
                    <th width="6">Payables</th>
                    <th width="6">Balance</th>
                    <th width="10">Last Week Details</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                      <td><a href="#">SITE A</a> </td>
                      <td><a href="#">200000</a></td>
                      <td><a href="#">110000</a></td>
                      <td><a href="#">36000</a></td>
                      <td><a href="#">79000</a></td>
                      <td>Completed kitchen tiles work</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td><a href="#">SITE B</a></td>
                      <td><a href="#">500000</a></td>
                      <td><a href="#">425000</a></td>
                      <td><a href="#">88000</a></td>
                      <td><a href="#">-13000</a></td>
                      <td>completed kitchen tiles work</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>TOTAL</td>
                      <td>700000</td>
                      <td>555000</td>
                      <td>124000</td>
                      <td>66000</td>
                      <td></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xm-12">
            <h3 class="side">
              Your to do list 
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xm-12">
            <button class="btn btn-success view" name="submit" type="submit">
              Add Item
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
            <div class="table-responsive line">
                <table class="table table-bordered dem">
                  <thead>
                    <tr class="hd">
                      <th width="3">Sr.</th>
                      <th width="15">Task</th>
                      <th width="15">Site</th>
                      <th width="15">Added</th>
                      <th width="20">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1</td>
                        <td>Need to co-ordinate with shahid bhai for comment bags</td>
                        <td>Site A</td>
                        <td>23-02-2016</td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="#">Delete Task</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">Mark as complete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Get registrations done</td>
                        <td>Site B</td>
                        <td>23-02-2016</td>
                        <td><a href="#">Delete Task</a> &nbsp; <a href="#">Mark as complete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xm-12">
            <h3 class="side">
              Quick Navigation 
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
            <div class="table-responsive line">
              <table class="table table-bordered dem">
                <tr class="hd">
                  <th>
                    <span>Select Site</span>
                    <select name="site" class="hig"> 
                      <option value="" selected="selected">Fetch site list</option>
                      <option value="site A">site A</option>
                      <option value="site B">site B</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="dis">Select Operations</span>
                      <select name="site" class="hig"> 
                      <option value="" selected="selected">select your option</option>
                      <option value="option 1">View Site-wise imcome statement</option>
                      <option value="option 2">View Site-wise vendors</option>
                      <option value="option 3">View Site-wise items list</option>
                      <option value="option 4">List of Vendors Vs Expenses</option>
                      <option value="option 5">List of Item Vs Expenses</option>
                      <option value="option 6">List of Labours Vs Expenses</option>
                      <option value="option 7">List of Service Vs Expenses</option>
                      <option value="option 8">Payables List</option>
                      <option value="option 9">To-do List</option>
                      <option value="option 10">Work Done List</option>
                    </select>
                    <button class="btn btn-success viewl" name="submit" type="submit" >GO</button>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </table>        
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xm-12">
            <h3 class="side">
              Reporting Definations 
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
            <div class="table-responsive line">
              <table class="table table-bordered dem">
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="info">
                    <td>View Site-wise imcome statement</td>
                    <td>Show Income Statement of a particular site</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>View Site-wise vendors</td>
                    <td>Show all the vandors of a perticular site</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="info">
                    <td>View Site-wise items list</td>
                    <td>Show all the Items registerd in a particular</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>List of Vendors Vs Expenses</td>
                    <td>List of all vandors registerd in a perticular site vs amount paid to them</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="info">
                    <td>List of Item Vs Expenses</td>
                    <td>List of all the Items used/registerd in a perticular site and the amount utilized on them</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>List of Labours Vs Expenses</td>
                    <td>List of the labours used in a perticular site and the amount paid to them</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="info">
                    <td>List of Service Vs Expenses</td>
                    <td>List of the Service used in a perticular site and the amount paid to them</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Payables List</td>
                    <td>List of Payables in  perticula site</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="info">
                    <td>To-do List</td>
                    <td>To-do List of a perticular site</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Work Done List</td>
                    <td>List of Works Done on a perticular site</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="info">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  

      <script>
        document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = Date();
      </script>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

index.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "index";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$email      =   $_POST['email'];
$password   =   $_POST['password'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO form ( email, password )
VALUES ( '$email', '$password')";



                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {


                header('Location: sign-up.html');

                   } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }

                $conn->close();



if($count == 1)
  {
    $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
    echo "Login worked";
    exit();
  }
else
  {
     $_SESSION['logged']=false;
     echo "Login failed";
     exit();
  }

?>

<li class='active' style='float:right;'>
  <?php 
  if($_SESSION['logged'] == true)
    { 
      echo $_SESSION["name"];
      echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></li>';
    }
  elseif($_SESSION['logged'] == false)
    {
      echo '<a href="sign-up.html"><span>Login/Register</span></a></li>';
    }



//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM form where email = $email and password = $password";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " Name: " . $row["name"]. ".<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
  ?>
```

Here after the user log in, it doesn't show the user name. I want to make it as the user name should be taken from the database file and displayed in the `maindash.html`. But it only shows me the Hello as written in my code.

Comment: You need to have a page with extension `.php` to work with `session` of `maindash.html`.

Comment: Looks like there's no session_start initialization in your maindash.html page. Maindash page should be a .php page beginning with <?php tag and including session_start() function at the  beginning.

Comment: I have this index.php in which I stored the session. You see above.

Comment: Yes but you can read session data only in your index.php page if you use this structure. .html page is not reading your session data

Comment: @Ace_Gentile Do I need to start session in maindash.html?

Comment: Where you are using `session_destroy()`? Show existing session values if not. Please use once and try.

Comment: don't forget that you need to start the session too. (in all files where you use the session)

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `maindash.html` page to have a `.php` extension. And at the top of the page (`maindash.php` i.e.) ensure you put

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
```

Comment: I created the php session and changed the extension maindash.html as php, but still I'm not getting the user name from database. As the user sign up with the email id and password.

Comment: Is there any mistake with mysql query??

Comment: Looking at your queries, you are exposed to SQL Injection but that's another issue on its own. The structure of your code looks kinda suspicious, you are setting `$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;` but the `$myusername` variable has not been created/defined. For this reason `$_SESSION['username']` will always be undefined. The code will make more sense if you set `$_SESSION['username']`  after fetching the result set from your login query. Set `$_SESSION['username'] = $row['name'];` in your `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` loop.